# JPA: Cascading OneToOne : which side should be the cascading attribute?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, cascading

So far my understand was that cascading only makes sense from the parent to the child.
Now I'm wondering: does this also applies to OneToOne relationships?

I'm asking because I found in our code many (unidirectional) OneToOne relationships with cascading from child to parent. I tested it with "persist" and it seems to work - meaning the transient child is persisted together with the transient parent. While looking in the literature I found examples of such a cascading strategy. For instance on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one):

```
// CHILD    
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//... 

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Address address;

}


//PARENT
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
private User user;
}
```

In some other articles, the cascading is done the other way around. For instance on [Vlad Mihalcea's blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).:

```
//CHILD
@Entity(name = "PostDetails")
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;

}

//PARENT
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
          fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private PostDetails details;

}
```

So at the end are they both two valid options? I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I am not a fan of `CASCADE`. Why? Simply because if you don't know what is going on, why use a thing?

I can't answer your question because it depends on what you think is correct. But I can help shed some light on the issues.

You need to understand the "owning entity". From the Javadocs:

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of the OneToOne annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.

In the first case, the `User` is the owning entity. In JPA, only the owning side will persist relationships. In this case only if the `Address` field is set in the `User` entity will JPA try to persist the relationship.

A persist operation would be:

```
public void initWithOwner() {
    Address a = Address.builder().build();
    userRepo.save(User.builder().address(a).build());
}
```

Which results in:

```
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into address (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into users (address_id, id) values (?, ?)
```

No problem there. But what if the the `Address` is already persisted?

```
public void initWithOwnerTransient() {
    try {
        Address a = addressRepo.save(Address.builder().build());
        userRepo.save(User.builder().address(a).build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SAVE ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into address (id) values (?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
SAVE ERROR: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.jpaplay.Address; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.jpaplay.Address
```

Using `Cascade` has problems because it's tring to insert both but the current address already exists. You can work around it:

```
private void initWithOwnerTransientFix() {
    try {
        User u = userRepo.save(User.builder().build());
        Address a = addressRepo.save(Address.builder().build());
        u.setAddress(a);
        u = userRepo.save(u);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SAVE ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Which results in this lovely bit of SQL:

```
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into users (address_id, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into address (id) values (?)
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_1_, user0_.address_id as address_2_1_1_, address1_.id as id1_0_0_ from users user0_ left outer join address address1_ on user0_.address_id=address1_.id where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select address0_.id as id1_0_0_ from address address0_ where address0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_1_, user0_.address_id as address_2_1_1_, address1_.id as id1_0_0_ from users user0_ left outer join address address1_ on user0_.address_id=address1_.id where user0_.address_id=?
Hibernate: update users set address_id=? where id=?
```

Or perhaps you could delete the existing address record first if it exists, but then you have to check first and so on. Not a bad solution. Be sure to do it in a transaction.

Or you could avoid using cascade altogether. You have to save both the `Address` and `User` yourself, or use an already saved instance, which also means you have to check first, but at least you "know" what you are doing.

```
private void initWithOwnerNoCascade() {
    try {
        AddressNoCascade a = addressNoCascadeRepo.save(AddressNoCascade.builder().build());
        userNoCascadeRepo.save(UserNoCascade.builder().address(a).build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SAVE ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into address (id) values (?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into usersnocascade (address_id, id) values (?, ?)
```

So, which side should you put the `Cascade` on? If you are going to insist on using it and making your life that much more complicated, it should go on the owning side of the relationship, in this case the `User`.

Or, just leave it out and be happy.